# Images rotated to 90 degree left email attachment iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

Well this may be a very easy Question but I'm not getting the answer after searching a lot.

I have one application in which I send the image taken from camera. The path of image captured from camera is stored in database. So in mail attachment code I load image from path and attach like this:

```
     UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:ImagePath];
     NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
     [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Spotted"];
```

but the image is rotated by 90 Degree left every time. Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong here??

**P.S.: `NSLog` of `ImagePath` -->
 /var/mobile/Applications/4BFB1BD9-DD83-42AF-A2BF-A5E4CC0DEAE3/Documents/459443.png**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been some [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2477227?start=0&tstart=0) on the Apple site about this issue in pictures sent by mail.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need it to be a PNG, I suggest converting it to a JPEG.  JPEGs are more compressed (useful when it comes to email) and don't seem to have this rotating problem.  Try using `NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage);` instead.

I've twisted my brain on this problem for several days as well.  If you need it to be a PNG, here's a pretty good write up of what I learned on the topic:  [iOS PNG Image rotated 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307521/ios-png-image-rotated-90-degrees)

Comment: thnx, i was converting into png