# Image is rotated after capture it with camera and save with PNG format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm building an app that takes a photo and show it on the screen (that's the relevant part).
For some reason when I take the image from camera save it as PNG and display it it's rotated. It doesn't happen if the image is taken from camera roll.

Does someone have the same issue or can help?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot on what you mean? Is it a true rotate, or is it a flip?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS PNG Image rotated 90 degrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307521/ios-png-image-rotated-90-degrees)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue when saving it as a PNG on iPhone.  The PNG is rotated.  You need to correct for that.  It doesn't do this when you save as JPEG.

[iOS PNG Image rotated 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307521/ios-png-image-rotated-90-degrees)