# Image not rotating correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, image, cocoa

rotateI am trying to rotate my images by 90 degrees. It works without the rotate, but when I rotate and translate it doesn't show. What am i doing wrong?

```
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"check" ofType:@"jpg"];
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImage.size);
//CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), newImage.size.width, 0);
//CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, newImage.size.width);
//CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 90);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newImage.size.height, newImage.size.width);   
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, newImage.CGImage);
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

ImageView.image = viewImage;
```

Comment: check this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307521/ios-png-image-rotated-90-degrees

Comment: CGContextRotateCTM uses angle in radians.. so M_PI_2 for 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my define statement and I needed to flip the image. Here is the completed code: ( The image has to be perfect because an OCR process the image and if it's even a little off, it gets rejected.

```
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(c);

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"check" ofType:@"jpg"];
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSLog(@"Rect width: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(newImage.size) );
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImage.size);
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, newImage.size.width);
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextTranslateCTM( UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.5f * newImage.size.width, 0.5f * newImage.size.height ) ;
CGContextRotateCTM( UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), radians( -90 ) ) ;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(-(newImage.size.height* 0.5f) + 200,  -(0.5f * newImage.size.width) + 200 , newImage.size.height - 200, newImage.size.width - 200);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, newImage.CGImage);

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
ImageView.image = viewImage;

CGContextRestoreGState(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using image view and use it's transform like so:

```
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage]; 
newImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

Comment: I can't use an image view because this image has to be sent to a server for image authorization.

Comment: You can always access the image from the imageview directly using `newImageView.image`

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImage.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90* M_PI/180); //Degrees should be in radians.

[newImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

UIImage *viewImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Good luck.

UPDATE:

Actually, this is a duplicate from [How to Rotate a UIImage 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)