# move_uploaded_file - prevent rotation / ignore exif data

Tags: php, ios, image, exif, bulletproof

working on a upload image feature for my custom CMS.

I have completed the feature, but have an image when uploading images from mobile devices. Only tested on IOS so far but the issue is:

If the user selects to take a picture and does so in portrait, when the image is saved it is rotated -90 degrees.

It is however fine in landscape. After some research I have found that it uses the exif data from an image and looks at the rotation. Is there a way to ignore this information and keep the image as it was taken?

Using a class to upload images I found on GitHub called bulletproof:

https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof

The link to the actual class:

https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof/blob/master/src/bulletproof.php

And this is the upload part from that:

```
$moveUploadedFile = move_uploaded_file($fileToUpload["tmp_name"], $this->uploadDir . "/" . $newFileName);
```

Thanks, Craig.

Answer (score 0):

This PHP class doesn't apply any image rotation. A search for `imagerotate()` fails.
So this is not PHP related and you might ensure that by testing the image upload from another, non-iOS client.

Then, you might want to find out, if iOS has a setting to send the native, unmodifed image or if you have to apply some "rotate"-correction on iOS-device side to get a correct rotation before sending.
In other words: i believe the image is transformed on IOS device side, before the image is send.

[iOS PNG Image rotated 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307521/ios-png-image-rotated-90-degrees)

[iOS4 landscape photos sideways in e-mail](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2477227?start=0&tstart=0)